# Does this permanent have a closed form?

Tags: matrices, matrix-analysis, determinants, permanent

What is the closed form of this permanent? (similar to the [Cauchy determinant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_matrix#Cauchy_determinants))

\begin{aligned}
f(z_1,z_2,\cdots,z_N,w_1,w_2,\cdots,w_N)=\left[
\small{\begin{matrix}
\frac{1}{(z_1-w_1)^2} && \frac{1}{(z_1-w_2)^2} && \cdots && \frac{1}{(z_1-w_N)^2} \\
\frac{1}{(z_2-w_1)^2} && \frac{1}{(z_2-w_2)^2} && \cdots && \frac{1}{(z_2-w_N)^2} \\
\vdots && \vdots && \ddots && \vdots \\
\frac{1}{(z_N-w_1)^2} && \frac{1}{(z_N-w_2)^2} && \cdots && \frac{1}{(z_N-w_N)^2} \\
\end{matrix}} \right]
\end{aligned}

Where $z$'s and $w$'s are complex numbers.

Comment: Why should it have a closed form?

Comment: @IgorRivin It's just so much similar to the Cauchy determinant, that I thought it might have a closed form.

Comment: If you think of how you get the closed form for the Cauchy determinant, you will see that _none_ of the tricks work here (OK, almost none), so I am a little skeptical.

Comment: For $n = 2$, the result is a fraction whose numerator is an irreducible degree-4 polynomial. If anything factors for higher $n$, then I don't think the factors will be any simpler than this polynomials...

Comment: @darijgrinberg Good point. I didn't consider that.

Comment: Also, one important reason for the celebrated Borchardt's identity for permanents and determinants allowing to compute the permanent of the Cauchy matrix $(a_{ij})$ is that the matrix $(a_{ij}^{-1})$ of inverse elements is of rank at most $2$. For the matrix you are considering, this is not true.